# How to deal with a "correct", but deleted answer because of ChatGPT

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Yesterday I was having a look at the newest question tagged with [twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twig) and came upon this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75304333/remove-p-tags-from-twigs-markdown-to-html), which already had a, now-deleted, decent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75304360/446594) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOYrz.png)).

At that time I felt the answer did a fair job at helping out OP to provide a solution, so it wouldn't make any sense for me to add an additional answer, because the answer seemed adequate enough already to help out OP, which OP confirmed in a comment

Anyhow, as I always keep track of questions I had "interactions" with, I revisited the question today and noticed the answer was deleted by a moderator, most likely due to the fact the answer raised suspicion as being a ChatGPT generated answer.

Which leads to my actual question: How do we do deal with this kind of situation?

If I were to add a new answer, it would be nearly identical to the deleted answer. 
Leading to the fact this could be seen as plagiarism, which is frowned upon as well. So I feel reluctant to add a new answer.

How can we proceed in this case?

Comment: Would there be a duplicate for this? I'm certainly not an expert but I'm suspicious this is the very first time such a question has been asked and answered.

Comment: If it's not a duplicate, how about posting your own, non-AI generated, answer?

Comment: @Larnu OP says *If I were to add a new answer, it would be nearly identical to the deleted answer. Leading to the fact this could be seen as plagiarism, which is frowned upon as well.*

Comment: I fail to see, in truth, how someone can't use their own words, @user10186832 . That the 2 answers recommend the same solution is irrelevant.

Comment: @user10186832 assuming this would indeed be the first (non-deleted) answer, it could at the very least link to some documentation.

Comment: @Larnu - *can't use their own words*. I feel like the deleted answer already explains the possible solution accurate enough. Sure you could change some words here and there, but the gist would be roughly the same

Comment: The gist being the same is fine, @DarkBee , as [blackgreen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4108803/blackgreen) states in their [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422989/2029983). The *important* thing is that you, writing your own content, isn't ChatGPT content copy pasta'd into the answer box with (likely) no fact checking or validation being performed. That ChatGPT actually got something *right* for once has no impact on the content you write.

Comment: That's kinda why I've posted this question as I work daily with `twig` and can validate the answer.

Comment: Why do you suspect it was generated by ChatGPT? It’s missing some key features of ChatGPT generated text.

Comment: @Security Hound: It isn't that clear, but look at the previous posts. They are very terse (some are effectively only [code dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74819344/how-to-correctly-pivot-the-table-data-in-postgres-using-case-statements-cross-t/74820784#74820784)). It looks like someone who became question-banned, posted late answers (mostly code dumps) to get out of the question ban, and finally resorted to ChatGPT (which produced complete English sentences) when that didn't work.

Comment: My guess would be, @SecurityHound , is that they (like many other users that contribute ChatGPT answers) posted many answers and that *any* recent answers from the user were deleted. *Maybe* that one wasn't, but I would not blame the mods for deleting *all* recent answer contributions if the first 5/6 they checked were ChatGPT, and 1 out of the recent 8 or  9 wasn't ChatGPT. If it truely isn't a ChatGPT answer then the user being discussed can always flag it for undeletion, and explain that they actually wrote the content.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't follow. How would someone who was Q-banned be able to "resort to" ChatGPT, while only being permitted to ask one new question per 6 months?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: Posting answers; they aren't answer-banned. A typical pattern for someone who is question-banned is an ***abrupt*** switch to *only* posting answers (after only having posted questions for many many years). It is conjecture that they are question-banned, of course, but the pattern is pretty clear. Often it is late answers (presumably to avoid downvotes and betting on the occasional spurious upvote) and in some cases plagiarised answers and/or completely bogus answers. And now it is sometimes ChatGPT-generated answers (that is much easier).

Comment: cont' - [Late answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review) with code dumps are pretty safe. Few will bother to check the technical merit and plagiarism check of code is very difficult, at least with primitive tools like Google Search (the easiest is if they copy code from existing answers to the *same* question).

Comment: Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript#comment132942270_41974453) I stumbled upon today. I don't particularly look out for plagiarism, and it took a while to dissect the case; another user's comment about missing attribution set it off. The plagiarism is a little bit more sophisticated: It has both text and code (thus does not *look* like a code dump), but both are plagiarised. The text is from another answer to the same question and the code from somewhere on the Internet. The answer is likely totally bogus.

Comment: cont' - Still the answer managed to get five upvotes. There are also a bunch of other code dumps for that question. It could be a study case to indicate how widespread the problem of plagiarism and bogus answers is for code dumps.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We are going to look at the bigger picture. We won't sanction your answer if the only issue we can find with it is that it contains a small excerpt of code that *might* also be produced by ChatGPT and/or is also mentioned in a deleted ChatGPT post.

In other words, even assuming that the code required to correctly address the problem is so specific and concise that an AI might produce the same output, you surely **can** provide additional content that would make your answer genuinely unique and high-quality, can't you? By the way, this is a generally applicable standard.

If you are able and willing to do so, then by all means post an answer, as if the deleted post didn't exist.

Of course if you post an answer that is identical to a deleted answer, then your answer would be equally subject to moderation because, well... it's identical. And yes, there is a hypothetical edge case where someone else's answer might be deleted by mistake, and by reposting it *verbatim* or nearly *verbatim* you would be "only" committing plagiarism (and/or circumventing moderation). However, why would you do that anyway? If you think a post is deleted by mistake, you can question it by raising flags or posting in Meta as appropriate.

So, don't get too concerned with deleted posts; just focus on contributing good content that complies with our guidelines, as you normally would if you didn't have the privilege to see deleted posts.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I've gone and requested more information from OP to be able to add a more extended answer than the current deleted one

Comment: Nicely put. The last paragraph pretty much succinctly summarises what I tried to say.